# C# + MySql exception: SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table *****

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, datagridview, xampp

I'm using C# + MySql + MySql connector to enter information into MySql database (via Xampp), And get the entered data back into a DataGridView.

When retrieving back the data, I get exceptions: (1) "SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'students'" and (2) "Host 'DELL-KL2001' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server". The 2nd exception occurs when I run the code while connected to the Net. I tried similar question that being answered, though I'm not able to detect my coding error. Could you guys please look at my code and give a tip about the error in my code? Much appreciated.

P.S. I've not typed erroneous DB or table names like the case in some other questions I've read.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MySqlBasics
{
public partial class FrmRegList : Form
{
    public FrmRegList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string MySqlConnectionString;

    private void FrmRegList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MySqlConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=student_reg.students;Uid=root;Pwd=pass";
    }

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int mobileNo;
        string mobile = tbMobNo.Text;
        int.TryParse(mobile, out mobileNo);

        MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(MySqlConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand sqlCmd;
        sqlConnection.Open();

        try
        {
            sqlCmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO students(Id, Name, MobileNo)VALUES(@Id, @Name, @MobileNo)";
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(tbId.Text));
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNo", mobile);
            MySqlDataReader mySqlReader;
            mySqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: btnEnter_Click()");
        }

        LoadDataFromForm();
    }

    private void LoadDataFromForm()
    {
        MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(MySqlConnectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        //try
        {
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM student_reg.students";

            MySqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            DataSet sqlDataset = new DataSet();
            sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDataset);
            dGridRegs.DataSource = sqlDataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
        //catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Error: LoadDataFromForm() " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnDebug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDataFromForm();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This seems like a MySql permissions issue, not a C# issue.

Comment: How do I get set the proper permission, please?

Comment: My question is marked as a Duplicate. But I cannot find a duplicate created by me on my question list (?)

Comment: It is not a duplicate that you have asked.  However, others have run into the exact same issue as you and there is already an answered question that explains how to resolve it.  You'll find the hyperlink to the duplicate at the top of this question.